# How to parse json object with variable key names using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json

I intend to use DataContractJsonSerializer to convert the json i'm receiving to an object, but the keys in the root can have any name, something similar to this:

```
{
"Jhon": {...},
"Lucy": {...},
"Robert": {...}
...
}
```

When the keys are fixed i can use `[DataMember(Name = "keyname")]` but in this case I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the structure of your object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings()
{
    UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true
});

var json = @"{
""Jhon"": { ""Name"": ""John""},
""Lucy"": {},
""Robert"": {}
}";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var results = serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class RootObject : Dictionary<string, User>
{
}
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This will do, thanks. I was hoping that something more object oriented existed, like if you could assign the string to a property of a class automagically, like, instead of Dictionary<string,User> you could have Dictionary<User,UserData> and User.Name got assigned the string somehow. Anyway, thank you, this helped a lot